# Store json object to html element with handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

how to store the json complete object in html element as a data attribute

```
var a = {name : "sample",age : "34"}
$.find('#someDiv").data("adata",a);
```

can we achive the same thing with handlebars while creating the template

```
<div id="someDiv" data-adata="{{a}}"></div>
```

is that possible?

Comment: right now i have stringyfied the json and stored it according as specified in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232574/handlebars-js-parse-object-instead-of-object-object ,is there any direct approch with handlebars

Comment: oops. I don't see your comment while answering :)

Comment: If you want to store a reference to the actual object instead of the JSON string, try this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313280/1075062

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't embed JSON perse in the HTML, since HTML is pure string and JSON not.

But you do can stringify it and store it there with a custom method like the following:

```
/*
 * Simple helper to stringify an object.
 * Usage: {{ JSON2string object }}
 */
Handlebars.registerHelper('JSON2string', function (object:Object) {
    return JSON.stringify(object);
});
```

Then, in the templates, you can use it like:

```
<div id="someDiv" data-adata="{{JSON2string a}}"></div>
```

Which effectively store a JSON string in the `data` attribute.