# How to register event on element in handlebars template, using data passed to that template

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, handlebars.js

In my ecommerce web app, a handlebars template for the cart is populated by the cart data model, obtained through an API.

this is how the view is created

```
Cart.prototype.createView = function() {

    // render cart handlebars template
    var html = this.template(this.model);

    // save rendered template as view
    this.view = $(html);

    // insert into DOM
    $('.cart').html('');
    this.view.clone(true).appendTo($('.cart'));

};
```

This is a part of the handlebars template

```
<ul class="items">

    {{#each contents}}

        <li>
            <span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
            <span class="price">{{this.pricing.rounded.with_tax}}</span>
            <span class="name">{{this.title}}</span>
            <span class="quantity">{{this.quantity}}</span>
        </li>

    {{/each}}
</ul>
...
```

Now how can I register an onClick event (e.g. with jQuery) to the `.remove` span, and use the data from the handlebars `#each` loop? In particular: the product ID, so I can do the "remove product from cart" button.

I know I could add the product ID to the DOM like so:

`<span data-product-id="{{this.id}}" class="remove">...</span>`

and then use it in the controller

```
Cart.prototype.initController = function() {
    var self = this;
    var container = $('.cart');

    // register click event on remove button
    container.on('vclick', '.remove', function() {

        // get product ID
        var productID = $(this).attr('data-product-id');

        // remove product from cart
        self.removeProduct(productID);
    });

};
```

**But I don't want to do it like this. I don't want to put the productID into the DOM.** So how can I properly register that event to the node created in a handlebars loop, while using the data that is passed to the template? I basically need to link the data to the view.

I don't want to use messy solutions like loop through the data and DOM list arrays and link them via their array index. I'm sure there is a proper MVC style solution that I'm not seeing.

Comment: easy: you can't. the template is just a string, so it needs a string to point it where to go, in your case a productID, which you forebode. you could inject a tempID in, and turn that tempID into a productID, is that's less reprehensible to your goals. you could also attach the events right after your appendTo() call, once it's an object.

Comment: hm. thanks for your comment. Attaching the event after the appendTo is no better than what I posted as I'm still not inside the #each loop to get the data (e.g. productID).
I'll rething the way I use handlebars templates. Maybe I find another way, because the options I have right now are really not how I want this done. Thanks again.

Comment: I may need to create the `li`'s in JavaScript myself instead of handlebars. Then I could easily attach events to it.

Comment: I've answered a similar duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313280/1075062. It's basically the same solution as dandavis with an example Handlebars helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a function one can use to tie a string template to an object, without putting any info from the object into the template.

```
var refData=[];
function ref(v){
    if(typeof v!=="object") return refData[v];
    var id=refData.indexOf(v);
    if(id==-1) id=refData.length;
    refData[id]=v;
    return id;
};
```

if you pass it an object, you get back an index number. if you pass it an index number, you get back an object. You can reset the cache by setting refData.length=0; To use this in a template, you need to use a helper, which handlerbars supports. you put the index from passing an object into the template with that helper, and in your click events, you can wrap the call around index to get an object in-place. for example:

```
<input id={{ref}} onclick=alert(ref(this.id).someProperty) />
```

this is completely separate from handlebars or any model/template package, so it's portable, small, and easy to use. Sure, built-in 2-way data binding is more powerful, but not everything has it yet, and this is certainly better than mixing view creation metaphors.